# php script does not work for too many records

Tags: php, mysql

The following php script works fine if i run it on my MYSQL table with less than 200 records but if the number of records exceeds 200, then it returns a blank screen. Please help.

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$username='user';
$pwd='pass';
$db='myDB';
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$pwd,$db) or die('Unable to connect');
if(mysqli_connect_error($con))
{
    echo "Failed to Connect to Database ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql='SELECT * FROM MyTable';
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($result)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $data[]=$row;
    }

    print(json_encode($data));
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: And what does it put in your PHP Error log? That is always the first place you should look!!

Comment: Alternatively ... Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Odds are that you're hitting memory limits

Comment: @MarkBaker Of course the rows could be HUGE

Comment: ...and Lord (and them) only knows what's in there and how many columns and their values.